# Covid Travel Insurance

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, insurance

I'm planning a trip from the United States to Botswana with a stopover in South Africa in the second half of August this year. While I have no personal Covid concerns as I'm fully-vaccinated, I know that the countries I'm visiting aren't at this point as advanced in their vaccine roll-outs as the United States is and both countries have a history of enforcing rather strict lockdowns. Considering that a resurgence is still a possibility in my destination countries, I would like protection from the financial impact of my flights potentially being canceled or of being forced into quarantine.

All the travel insurance options I've looked into only address what happens in case I get Covid. Due to my vaccination status, I consider such an eventuality too unlikely to insure against. Are there any options to insure against border closures, quarantines, etc.? I know that CFAR (cancel for any reason) is a possibility, but it seems like that would be unnecessarily expensive. Or can I expect my airline to take care of me in such an event (Qatar Airways and SA Airlink, booked on separate itineraries, in this case)?

I only found one other relevant question on this site, but it was asked last year and had no answers.

Comment: Even Allianz's new ["Epidemic Coverage Endorsement"](https://www.allianztravelinsurance.com/covid-19-faq.htm) only covers situations where you or a family member gets COVID or is ordered individually to quarantine, which isn't what you want insurance for. I'm not familiar with every travel insurance policy out there, but I'm not aware of any that are likely to cover changes in border and quarantine rules because they come so fast and are often unpredictable. Your best bet is probably to review the terms under which your airlines and lodging will permit you to change your travel dates.

Comment: The chances of such a thing happening are high enough that even if you can find insurance that covers it, you should expect the premium to cost a large fraction of the price of your trip.

Comment: Each airline will only help regarding getting you to where you paid them to get you. They won't help with separately booked onward flights. They *wanted you to* book with them for the entire journey, and would have provided that protection if you did.  Since you didn't...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.